# What are the implications of using NFS3 file system for multi-instance queue managers in WebSphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, nfs

We are stuck in a difficult scenario in our new MQ infrastructure implementation using multi-instance queue managers using WebSphere MQ v7.5 in Linux platform.
The concern is our Network Team is not able to configure NFS4 and hence we are still having the NFS3 version. We understand multi-instance queue managers will not function properly with NFS3. But are there any issues if we define queue managers in multi-instance fashion in NFS3 and expect to work perfect for single instance mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect you to have issues running single-node queue managers with NFS3, we do so on a regular basis.  The requirement for NFS4 was for the file locking mechanism required by multi-instance queue managers to determine when the primary instance has lost control and an a secondary queue manager should take over.

If you do define the queue manager as multi-instance, and the queue manager attempt to failover, it may not do so successfully, at worst it may corrupt your queue manager files.

If you control the failover yourself - as in, shutdown the queue manager on one node and start it again on another node - that should work for you, as there is no file sharing taking place and all files would be shutdown on the primary node before being opened on the secondary node.  You would have to make sure the secondary queue manager is NOT running in standby node -- ever.

I hope this helps.

Dave

Comment: @Dave Thanks! The worst is a concern for me. I have found the amqmfsck utility works even in NFS3. So if in a worst case the queue manager files gets locked or corrupted due to file locking mechanism in multi-instance queue manager I would not be able to recover both primary and secondary queue manager. Have you ever encountered such a scenario.